# Fedora 21 shutdown and reboot error

Tags: fedora, selinux

Recently I have been using Fedora 21 and I have an issue where sometimes I shut down and reboot and the system just hangs at the fedora logo and never actually boots. I noticed the issue after installing steam as I had an issue with the execheap preventing me from running games with intel drivers. To fix this I used `sudo su -c "setsebool -P allow_execheap 1"` I didn't want to disable selinux completely as I had read it wasn't a good idea.

I noticed this shutdown error only after using that but it isn't consistent and only happens at certain times. Is this something that could cause the issue that forces me to boot twice or is this just a coincidence. If it is the cause, is there a fix other than just changing the value back whenever I exit steam?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same-similar problem with fedora-21 on my desktop.  In my case, I had activated automaticlogin (/etc/gdm/custom.conf) and then I would have to boot twice almost every time - it would hang at the same point, the F/infinity logo the first time.  I used the command "journalctl -b" 
to see boot errors and noticed that "keyring" was mentioned several times.
I used seahorse to change the keyring's password entirely: changed to a blank, no password, (null).  (seahorse: under Passwords on Login right click and select Change Password {by default it is your user password})  That fixed it for me.

Comment: I'll check when I am home and see if I notice any similar trend. I do not use auto login though.